# Can SQL Server 2008 Linked Servers be edited? Is there the equivalent of an ALTER statement for Linked Servers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have a Linked Server which was made using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

If the linked server destination changes, I will have to change the properties of it to direct to the right place.

But I cannot - there is no edit option!

Am i missing something, or can Linked Servers not be altered?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Linked server name cannot be modified. It needs to be dropped and recreated in case the server name changes.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't modify a Linked Server

But if you right click the server in Management Studio and then:

**Script Linked Server As > DROP and CREATE to > New Query Editor Window**

You can make changes to the script and it's almost the same workflow as using **ALTER**

Answer (score 0):

The ability to edit them left around SQL 2000 or SQL 2005, now they have to be dropped and re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [sp_setnetname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190318.aspx).  You can use it to change the data_source of the linked server (destination), e.g.:

```
DECLARE @name sysname = 'SRVRNAME';
DECLARE @datasource sysname = 'srvr.name.com';

EXECute sp_setnetname @server = @name, @netname = @datasource;
```